i need to conditionally disable unchecked checkboxes. reactjs
the user selects an option from a dataset and that calls an api. the api brings back an object with an array nested inside and those values are listed as checkboxes. the api also brings back a key named choose(const name primaryMax) signifying the amount of checkboxes that can be checked.
when you check a box it puts the name of that input into an array and when the array.length >= primaryMax it should lock any checkbox that is not already checked. you still need to be able to uncheck a checked box, which will re-enable the other checkboxes.
right now i have it set to disable the checkboxes when array.length >= primaryMax but it disables all of them.  if the checkbox is checked it should be excluded from being disabled
//this sets the primaryMax to the choose value
//the api data starts at proficiency_choices
useEffect(() => {
    const primaryChoices = character?.class?.primary?.proficiency_choices
    setPrimaryMax(primaryChoices?.choose)
}, [primaryChoices])



useEffect(() => {

    const primaryProChoice = () => {
    
        const primaryChoices = character?.class?.primary?.proficiency_choices
        const secondaryChoices = character?.class?.secondary?.proficiency_choices

        const isEmpty = Object.keys(character?.class?.primary).length === 0
        const isSecondaryEmpty = Object.keys(character?.class?.secondary).length === 0
        
        //bard is set up differently so i excluded it and will add logic later to include it
        if(!isEmpty && character.class.primary.name !== 'Bard'){
            
            console.log(primaryMax)
       
            const isDisabled = chosenProPrimary.length >= primaryMax ? true : false   
            
            return setPrimaryProDiv(
                <div>
                    {primaryChoices[0].desc}
                    {primaryChoices[0].from.options.map((option, i) => {
                        //       
                        let isChecked

                        const handleCheck = (e) => {

                            
                            console.log(e)
                            const beenChecked = e.target.checked
                            if(beenChecked){
                                isChecked = true
                                setChosenProPrimary((prevPro) => [...prevPro, e.target.name])
                            }else if (!beenChecked){
                                isChecked = false
                                setChosenProPrimary((currentPro) => currentPro.filter((x) => x !== e.target.name))
                            }
                            console.log(chosenProPrimary)

                    
                        }

                        

                        return(
                            <p key={i}>
                               <input
                                    type='checkbox'
                                    name={option.item.index}
                                    onChange={handleCheck}
                                    disabled={isChecked ? false : isDisabled}
                                    
                                    />
                                <label htmlFor={option.item.index}>{option.item.name}</label> 
                            </p>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            )
                
            
        }
    
    }
    primaryProChoice()

//chosenProPrimary is the object selected from the dataset. it has all of the data from the api call

}, [chosenProPrimary, primaryMax])

i tried putting decideDisabled into the .map function, but it still disables every input

The isDisabled variable is being evaluated once for all checkboxes based on the length of chosenProPrimary, so it affects all checkboxes at once.
You should evaluate whether each checkbox should be disabled individually based on whether it's checked and whether the maximum number of selections has been reached. Reckon you should move the logic to decide whether a checkbox should be disabled inside the .map function.
const primaryProChoice = () => {
    const primaryChoices = character?.class?.primary?.proficiency_choices;

    const isEmpty = Object.keys(character?.class?.primary).length === 0;

    if (!isEmpty && character.class.primary.name !== 'Bard') {
        return (
            <div>
                {primaryChoices[0].desc}
                {primaryChoices[0].from.options.map((option, i) => {
                    const isChecked = chosenProPrimary.includes(option.item.index);
                    const isDisabled = chosenProPrimary.length >= primaryMax && !isChecked;

                    const handleCheck = (e) => {
                        const checkboxName = option.item.index;

                        if (e.target.checked) {
                            setChosenProPrimary((prevPro) => [...prevPro, checkboxName]);
                        } else {
                            setChosenProPrimary((currentPro) => currentPro.filter((x) => x !== checkboxName));
                        }
                    };

                    return (
                        <p key={i}>
                            <input
                                type='checkbox'
                                name={option.item.index}
                                onChange={handleCheck}
                                checked={isChecked}
                                disabled={isDisabled}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor={option.item.index}>{option.item.name}</label>
                        </p>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

So, isChecked variable checks if the checkbox is already checked.
isDisabled variable checks whether the checkbox should be disabled on your conditions.

that worked. thank you so much, that took up way more of my time than it should have

@ChristopherDirksen, no worries! Glad it helped, please consider accepting the answer so future users can find the solution. Cheers
